# Having problems with deploying Vite React app on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, vite, heroku-cli

I'm having problem with my app. I've successfully pushed all the files onto the site, but I've discovered that it's starting my app with npm start. I need it to use 'npm run dev' instead.
[image: heroku logs --tail]

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to create a start script and put the command you want to run in production.

If you want the same command, put the 'dev' script's code in 'start' script

As 'dev' script contains command for development and 'start' should contain production script.